# how to access the mp4 video on web which is password protected

Tags: java, authentication, vaadin, http-authentication

I am using vaadin video to integrate some videos in my application.
These videos are on web which are password protected. I am using following approach but its not working for me. It keeps asking me for username and password.

```
        URL url = new URL(Constants.VIDEO_HTTP_ADDRESS + fileName + ".mp4");
        URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
        String userpass = Constants.VIDEO_HTTP_ADDRESS_USERNAME + ":" + Constants.VIDEO_HTTP_ADDRESS_PASSWORD;
        String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
        uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);

....
....
        final Video v = new Video(label);
        ExternalResource fileResource;

        fileResource = new ExternalResource(url);
        v.setSources(fileResource);
```

I have user name and password, I want to integrate these videos in my application, so that they dont need the username and password explicitly.

Comment: does ``setRequestProperty`` actually result in a http header?

Comment: How do I check?

Comment: According to the documentation it should. But: You are not using the ``URLConnection`` in your ``ExternalResource``. You use the ``URL`` instance. That means that your header manipulation has no effect.

Comment: you could use an intercepting proxy (ZAP or OWASP) and have a look at the traffic.

Comment: Or wireshark so you don't need a proxy. Have you tried modifying the URL itself so it looks like "http://username:password@hostname/path/file.mp4"?

Comment: I tried to use it username:password@hostname/path/file.mp4 directly on browser, but that didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by @f1sh in his comment, you need to use your `URLConnection` to get the video resource. Instead of `ExternalResource` you can use  `StreamResource` which allows to load the resource from provided `InputStream`.

Something like that should work:

```
Video v = new Video();
v.setSource(new StreamResource(new StreamSource() {

    @Override
    public InputStream getStream() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(Constants.VIDEO_HTTP_ADDRESS + fileName + ".mp4");
            URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
            String userpass = Constants.VIDEO_HTTP_ADDRESS_USERNAME + ":" + Constants.VIDEO_HTTP_ADDRESS_PASSWORD;
            String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
            uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
            return uc.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //add some exception handling here
        }
    }

}, fileName + ".mp4"));
```

Comment: Above code gives me error that "This type of video file isnot supported"

Comment: When exactly are you getting this error? I just checked my code with some public mp4 video and it works, so it may be the problem with your `URLConnection`. Are you sure that it is correct? Can you save the video from `uc.getInputStream()` to some file (without the use of vaadin) and check if it works?

Comment: it did work, but it is slowing down. I have 10 videos and I think this part of codes, tries to stream all the videos at once, which slows down the whole process.